# htacces issues throws me an 404 error in register page and 500 error in login pages

Tags: docker, apache, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Im struggled with this, any help is appreciated. the .htaccess is in /var/www/html/apl/, and rewrite module is enabled aswell

I dont know why my subdirectory htaccess throws me an error in docker environment with php:7.4-apache image, while it works well outside of docker environment. ( i know u might be think drag or somethin, but i just think i need an improvement following trends with docker environment)

In docker logs it just showed "GET /apl/register" 500 211 and same as 404, doesnt gives me any specific clues/errors that i needed to solve this.
If i removes my htaccess both of my register and login content throws the same 404 error.

Comment: " .htaccess is in /var/www/html/apl/" - presumably `index.php` is also in the same directory? Otherwise, there's nothing "wrong" with the `.htaccess` file you've posted. You should check Apache's error log for the details of the 500 error.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, theres nothin wrong with your htaccess.

If u using a laravel project here, make sure u check again your routing library.